# How can I implement horizontal scrolling in a vertical pdf?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, pdf, uiwebview

I am trying to create a pdf viewing app in swift, with horizontal paging like an ebook reader.  I have been using a webview and setting pagination properties, but with no luck. Should i be using the UIWebView.scrollView properties instead?Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 

    @IBOutlet var pdfWebView: UIWebView! 

    func showPdf(pdfName: String?, pdfView: UIWebView?) { 
        var pdfName: String! = "" 
        var pdfLocation: NSURL! = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("\(pdfName)", ofType: "pdf")!) 
        let request: NSURLRequest! = NSURLRequest(URL:pdfLocation) 
        pdfView!.loadRequest(request) 
        pdfView!.paginationMode = UIWebPaginationMode.LeftToRight
        pdfView!.paginationBreakingMode = UIWebPaginationBreakingMode.Page
        pdfView!.pageLength = CGFloat(1000) 
        pdfView!.gapBetweenPages = CGFloat(5) 
    } 
    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        super.viewDidLoad()  
        showPdf("MVA", pdfView: pdfWebView) 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but is there a `UIWebView.contentsize` like method. Than you set the content width to get a horizontal scroll. But I think this is not standard behaviour of UIWebView. Why you don't use a UIPAgeViewController to have these effect? Apple also do this in iBooks.

Comment: The PDF I am displaying has embedded hyperlinks, so I'm not sure how it would translate to a UIPageViewController... The UIWebView Documentation seems to have the pagination feature I am looking for, I just cannot for the life of me get it to work.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Solved? kindly help me. @JamieDevNoob

Comment: Same here. Anyone get an answer to this? Im loading a pdf from a local file i download into the Applicaiotn Support directory. It loads the pdf in the webview but i can only see it in vertical mode. Any ideas?